# Jasper Report ireport 5.6.0 Comparing Doubles Condition not working

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a lots of problems with comparing double values in JasperReports. Nothing of what I am doing works.

It must show 3 different messages depends of a Double Value. The code is:

```
($P{number}.doubleValue() <= 1.0 ? msg($R{report.text2a}, $P{marshall}) :
 ($P{number}.doubleValue() > 1.0 && $P{number}.doubleValue() <= 2.0 ? msg($R{report.text2b}, $P{marshall}) : msg($R{report.text2c}, $P{marshall}))
)
```

The parameter "number" is correct because It has been showed before in the report and it has been printed, but when I generate the PDF , nothing is showed.

If value is less than 1, one text, if it's between 1 and 2, second text, and more that 2, third text.

Any help?

Comment: Your test seems good, maybe the issue comes from the result ? Just try to print simple String instead of `msg[..]`

Comment: @DeathGun You should post the test *jrxml*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a more recent version of jasper and didn't see a solution here. I'm not sure why, but sometimes jasper would break when comparing double values and sometimes it would work. What worked for me was creating an intermediate variable with the comparison. Something like:

```
<variable name="numberLTEqual" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$P{number}<=0]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

and then using the variable instead of the test:

```
$V{numberLTEqual} ? msg($R{report.text2a}, $P{marshall}...
```